# Camunda Multi-Tenancy processes.xml

Tags: business-process-management, multi-tenant, camunda

I'm new to camunda bpm and am doing a PoC by following the tomcat packaging ver 7.2. In my eclipse-maven project, I have one .bpmn file under each of the folder (tenant1, tenant2, all) located under /src/main/resources/processes. While I'm able to configure the models to be deployed separately to named tenant engines, I'm not able to configure for deploying the models under 'all' folder to all the engines (tenant1 and tenant2)

Here is my processes.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<process-application
  xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/ProcessApplication"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <process-archive name="tenant1-archive">
    <process-engine>tenant1</process-engine>
    <properties>
      <property name="resourceRootPath">classpath:processes/tenant1/</property>    
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
      <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
    </properties>
  </process-archive>
  <process-archive name="tenant2-archive">
    <process-engine>tenant2</process-engine>
    <properties>
      <property name="resourceRootPath">classpath:processes/tenant2/</property>
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
      <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
    </properties>
  </process-archive>

</process-application>​
```

The above config works fine but when I add this config to be able deploy models under folder 'all' to all the available engines, it fails. Note that I'm using an asterisk to specify all engines which is what I'm not sure of. How do I do this (specify multiple or all engines)?

```html
   <process-archive name="all-archive">
   <process-engine>*</process-engine>
    <properties>
      <property name="resourceRootPath">classpath:processes/all/</property>    
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
      <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
    </properties>
  </process-archive>​
```

Thanks.!

Answer (score 2):

Something like a wildcard or a regular expression that you tried to use is not supported in the `process-engine` element.

I think you have to create an "all-archive" for each tenant by writing something like

```
<process-archive name="all-archive-tenant1">
  <process-engine>tenant1</process-engine>
  <properties>
    <property name="resourceRootPath">classpath:processes/all/</property>    
    <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
    <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
  </properties>
</process-archive>

<process-archive name="all-archive-tenant2">
  <process-engine>tenant2</process-engine>
  <properties>
    <property name="resourceRootPath">classpath:processes/all/</property>    
    <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property>
    <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
  </properties>
</process-archive>
```

Comment: Thanks @thorben for the answer. This looks like a workaround to me because this is just pointing the same resourceRootPath to individual engine which is similar to what I did for other two archives. The reason why I call it a workaround is that I'm looking for a generic configuration so I don't have to repeat the same config 'n' number of times if there are 'n' engines which is not practical for a large value of 'n'.

Comment: Hi Jayavardhan, I understand the problem. However, afaik there is no way of declaring a single process-archive deployment for multiple engines. You might want to file a feature request in the Camunad JIRA: https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM

Comment: Thanks thorben. I'd like to vote for your comment suggesting to file a feature request but it doesn't let me do that since I don't have enough points I guess.